# Conditions of Fubini's theorem

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I read already some answer about this matter but I'm still unsure. 
If i have $E[\int_0^tX_sds]$ where X is some stochastic process, and if I want to interchange expectation with integral, which are the conditions that i have to verify before applying Fubini?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_s$ is  measurable process in the sense $(s,\omega) \to X_s(\omega)$ is measurable on $[0,t]\times\Omega$ and if $\int_{\Omega \times [0,t] } |X_s(\omega)| d(P\times m) <\infty$ (where $m$ is the Lebesgue measuer) then we can apply Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: so for example, if i have $X_s=B_s^2$ where B is the B.M., since i know it to be a.s. continuous then for each t we have $\int_{\Omega \times [0,t] } |X_s(\omega)| d(P\times m) <\infty$, and I can always apply Fubini, right?

Comment: @Alias__ Yes any process with continuous paths is a measurable  process and the integrability condition also holds for Brownian Motion .

Comment: 1) So $\int_{\Omega \times [0,t] } |X_s(\omega)| d(P\times m) <\infty$ actually it mean that I have to know that $E[\int_0^tX_sds] < \infty $, right?  2) which are the other possible conditions that allow me to apply Fubini? i guess that one is the case when $X_s$ is non negative, right? There are other one?