# Application of Tonelli-Fubini Theorem?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, brownian-motion, expected-value, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $(\Omega\text{, }\mathcal{F}\text{, }\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\{B_t\}_{t\geq0}$ be a standard Brownian Motion.

Consider $\text{Var}\left(\displaystyle \int_{0}^t B_sds\right)$. We have:
$$
\text{Var}\left(\displaystyle \int_{0}^t B_sds\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\displaystyle\int_0^t B_sds \displaystyle\int_0^t B_udu\right)\tag{1}
$$
At this point, I know that one can state that:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\displaystyle\int_0^t B_sds \displaystyle\int_0^t B_udu\right)=\displaystyle\int_0^t ds\displaystyle\int_0^t du \hspace{0.2cm} \mathbb{E}\left(B_sB_u\right)\tag{2}
$$

My **question** is: *why does $(2)$ hold true? Is that an application of Tonelli-Fubini Theorem? If so, how is it specifically applied? How does the 'swapping integrals' process precisely occur?*

Comment: No, I have edited, I was confusing, I meant Tonelli-Fubini. Cantelli and Tonelli confuse me :)

Comment: It is about swapping integrals and using Fubini. It has nothing to do with Borel-Cantelli;

Comment: Yes, as just said, I was confusing and I have immediately edited. Specifically, why am I allowed to apply Fubini? Could you please explain step-by-step how 'swapping process' occur? @Maximal_inequality

Comment: I guess this thread answers your question , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499158/conditions-of-fubinis-theorem; Using continuity of the sample paths is crucial here to claim boundedness .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fubini applies if we can show that
$$\int_{\Omega \times [0,t] \times [0,t]} |B_s(\omega)B_u(\omega)|(\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda\otimes \lambda)(d\omega, ds,du) < \infty$$

However, now the integrand is positive and for positive functions we can use Fubini for positive functions (= Tonelli) freely:

$$\int_{\Omega \times [0,t] \times [0,t]} |B_s(\omega)B_u(\omega)|(\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda\otimes \lambda)(d\omega, ds,du) $$
$$= \int_0^t \int_0^t \mathbb{E}[|B_s B_u|] ds du$$

The last integral is finite, which I leave to you as a good exercise on Brownian motion.

Comment: Great, thanks :)) So, I deduce that $$\int_0^t \int_0^t \mathbb{E}[|B_s B_u|] ds du=\int_0^t ds\int_0^t du\mathbb{E}[|B_s B_u|]$$ right? @ε-δ

Comment: Yes, then if $s > u$ use $|B_s B_u| = |((B_s- B_u)+B_u)B_u| \leq |B_s-B_u||B_u| + B_u^2$ and thus $E[|B_s B_u|] \leq E[|B_s-B_u|]E[|B_u|] + E[|B_u|^2]$ using independence of $B_s-B_u, B_u$. And then try to continue. Similarly, if $s < u$ find an expression and combine these expressions to get a good upper bound involving $\min\{s,u\}$. This will result in integrating something you can manage.

Comment: I can add more details later but I'm currently studying for an exam so that will be tomorrow.

Comment: Great, thank you. Obviously, **only when you are available**, I would like to have a confirmation about the fact that $\int_{\Omega \times [0,t] \times [0,t]} |B_s(\omega)B_u(\omega)|(\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda\otimes \lambda)(d\omega, ds,du)$ denotes a *triple integral* (an integral wrt probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ and the other two with respect to time $t$), hence it holds that $$\int_{\Omega \times [0,t] \times [0,t]} |B_s(\omega)B_u(\omega)|(\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda\otimes \lambda)(d\omega, ds,du)= \mathbb{E}\left(\displaystyle\int_0^t B_sds \displaystyle\int_0^t B_udu\right)$$ @ε-δ

Comment: In the meanwhile, I can already accept the answer, since it is very clear :) and good luck for your exam! @ε-δ

Comment: Yes, it is a triple integral.

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Did you manage to get any progress with the hints I provided?

Comment: Yes, work in progress but your advice is turning out to be very useful, as always. Thank you!!!!!